# cssClass.selectorText change in firefox browsers

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

im facing a problem when i try to change the selector text on a css class while im on firefox browsers.

What i have tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < styleSheet.cssRules.length; j++) {
            rule = styleSheet.cssRules[j];

            // identifies the keyframe rule bearing the same name as the class without the point in the beginning
            if ((rule.type == rule.KEYFRAMES_RULE || rule.type == rule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) && rule.name === className.substr(1)) {
                keyframesRule = rule;
            }

            // identifies the class rule named like the function argument effect
            if (rule.selectorText == className) {
                animationRule = rule;
                mainSheet = styleSheet;
            }
        }
    }

for (var l = 0; l < nrOfElements; l++) {
        classAttributes = animationRule.cssText;
        mainSheet.insertRule(classAttributes, mainSheet.cssRules.length);
        newClasses = mainSheet.cssRules[mainSheet.cssRules.length - 1];
        newClasses.selectorText = newClassName[l];
        console.log(newClasses.selectorText);
        console.log(newClassName[l]);
        newClasses.style.setProperty((vendorPrefix + "animation-name"), newClassName[l].substr(1));
}
```

Unfortunately, the first console return `.WPANIM` while the second returns `.WPANIM + incrementor` .

Question:

Why `cssClass.selectorText` cant be changed with something else while on firefox browers?

Answer (score 1):

Setting .selectorText is not implemented in Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37468

That issue is there since 16 years, feel free to vote on the left or fix it)